# How to remove all NSUser Defaults except two objects?

Tags: objective-c, nsuserdefaults

I am using a lot NSUserDefaults and i want every time the app starts to remove them except two objects is this somehow possible?

Any help appreciated

Comment: If you remove them every time the app starts, why use NSUserDefaults in the first place?  Just keep the attributes in you AppDelegate or in a singleton.

Comment: Thanks but this is how i have done it

Comment: I recommend refactoring that part of your app, it looks like you're using `NSUserDefaults` for things that are constantly changing or being needed to load into memory. A solution is load them in your `AppDelegate`, as stated by @HotLicks.

Comment: @stefanosn You can refactor your code to use another (in-memory) mechanism nearly as fast as it will take you to add a bunch of needless code to delete all but two values from `NSUserDefaults`.

Comment: "This is how I have done it" is not the way to produce good quality, robust code.

Comment: Thank you all guys for telling me your suggestions! I am accepting Cameron's answer because this was what i needed. I know i am wrong doing it this way i will fix it in the feature but at the moment i needed to clear NSUserDefaults. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you know which two objects you want to keep? If that's the case use this code:

```
id obj1 = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey@"keyForObj1"];
id obj2 = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey@"keyForObj2"];

NSString *appDomain = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleIdentifier];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] removePersistentDomainForName:appDomain];

[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:obj1 forKey:@"keyForObj1"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:obj2 forKey:@"keyForObj2"];
```

Comment: Thanks Cameron this was the code i needed although i am wrong using NSUserDefaults. Thank you all guys for telling me your suggestions!

Answer (score 1):

You would need to keep track of the keys yourself and remove the objects associated with them on launch.  More importantly, though: why are you storing data in NSUserDefaults that you only want to persist through a single run of the app?  That sort of data should probably be kept in memory.

Comment: This is how i did it i need to find a solution other than writing again the code :)

Answer (score 1):

You can save Those two items under separate a key and Add into the Code during ViewDidLoad.
Let me know the Actual Problem.

Comment: The problem is that is slowing down my app when trying to retrieve or save to nsuserdefaults. This happens after days of usage of my app.

Comment: @stefanosn - Then don't use NSUserDefaults!  You're abusing it.

Comment: Use Plist or Core Data Then for Easy Persistence

Comment: @akshatanil -- Except that apparently he doesn't need persistence.